# CSS Delay Transition Effect after className change?

Tags: css, transition

I have CSS code as follows

```
#example { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 500ms; }
#example.visible { opacity: 1; }
```

using this JavaScript to make it visible

```
setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById('example').className = 'visible'
}, 500)
```

As you can see, my intention is for a half second delay to pass before the div is made visible.

If I was to continue using JavaScript, I would need to use `clearTimeout` in case the 'make visible' requirement was cancelled before the first 500ms.

Is there a way to use CSS for this initial delay instead? That would allow me to simplify my JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

There is a delay option in css transitions

```css
#example { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 500ms 500ms;}
#example.visible { opacity: 1; }
```

```js
document.getElementById('example').className = 'visible'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/68uUV/